# How to pass a document from one REST API to another REST API without downloading the document

Tags: python

I am sitting between 2 SaaS's both with their own REST API.  I would like to grab documents from API(1) and pass it to API(2) without downloading the documents.  I am able to do both of these operations separately, but it seems like it would be a waste of time to download and save a pdf and then turn it around to POST it to API(2).  My sample code is below...

Any help is appreciated

Thanks!!!

Retreiving the document

```
import requests
import json
from datetime import date, datetime
import os

os.chdir(mypath)
url = "https://api.myapi_1.com/documents"
headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer {token}",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
}
params = {
"fund_id": "fund_1",
"data_date_start": datetime.strftime(today(), "%Y-%m-%d"),
}

response = requests.get(url,  headers=headers,  params=params,)
The_Document = Path(str(sub_list[n]) + ' ' + fund + ' ' + pool + suffix)
The_Document.write_bytes(new_file.content)
```

Posting the document

```
attachment = 'C:\\my_path_to_attachment\\The_Document.pdf'
attach_name = os.path.split(attachment)[-1]

r = requests.Session()
r.auth = (user, password)
post_url = 'https://myapi_2/entry/?entities=' + fund
post_params = {'body': body,
               'subject': subject,
               'entrytype': note_type,
               'x-_EffectiveDate': xstr(eff_date),
               'x-_FundName': fund,
               'x-_Type': ftype,
               'x-_Account' + link_pool: pool,
               }
r.post(post_url, data=post_params, files={'attachment': (attach_name, open(attachment, 'rb'))}, verify=False)
```

Comment: Maybe try saving the document from API(1) as byte array - keep in memory (assuming the file sizes are not big) and simply send the byte array to API(2). Another option is to create socket connection to both API(1) and API(2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't be possible unless...

- ...api 2 initiates the GET request to api 1 to retrieve the data.
- ...or api 1 POSTs the data to api 2.

The question would be if e.g. api 2 provides some functionality where you e.g. could send the url to the file and it fetches it for you. If they don't you would unfortunately have to download it first and then post it as you do in your example.

Comment: OK - thanks for the info, I will have to download them then as API(2) would charge for a third party to complete the GET request.  API(1) would probably also charge for this.